# open new tab when user click anywhere on the page only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need some help about this, i want to know how to open new tab when user click anywhere on the page only once. It's for my blogger. I have this code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

    var popup = function() {

        window.open ("http://example.com", "Window","status=1,toolbar=1,width=500,height=300,resizable=yes");
    }

</script>
<body onclick="popup()">
    <h1>Click anywhere!</h1>
</body>
```

But doesn't work because every click open a new tab, i tried this code with cookies

```html
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

<!-- Begin
var expDays = 1; // number of days the cookie should last

var page = "only-popup-once.html";
var windowprops = "width=300,height=200,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes";

function GetCookie (name) {
var arg = name + "=";
var alen = arg.length;
var clen = document.cookie.length;
var i = 0;
while (i < clen) {
var j = i + alen;
if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg)
return getCookieVal (j);
i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
if (i == 0) break;
}
return null;
}
function SetCookie (name, value) {
var argv = SetCookie.arguments;
var argc = SetCookie.arguments.length;
var expires = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : null;
var path = (argc > 3) ? argv[3] : null;
var domain = (argc > 4) ? argv[4] : null;
var secure = (argc > 5) ? argv[5] : false;
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) +
((expires == null) ? "" : ("; expires=" + expires.toGMTString())) +
((path == null) ? "" : ("; path=" + path)) +
((domain == null) ? "" : ("; domain=" + domain)) +
((secure == true) ? "; secure" : "");
}
function DeleteCookie (name) {
var exp = new Date();
exp.setTime (exp.getTime() - 1);
var cval = GetCookie (name);
document.cookie = name + "=" + cval + "; expires=" + exp.toGMTString();
}
var exp = new Date();
exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (expDays*24*60*60*1000));
function amt(){
var count = GetCookie('count')
if(count == null) {
SetCookie('count','1')
return 1
}
else {
var newcount = parseInt(count) + 1;
DeleteCookie('count')
SetCookie('count',newcount,exp)
return count
   }
}
function getCookieVal(offset) {
var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);
if (endstr == -1)
endstr = document.cookie.length;
return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
}

function checkCount() {
var count = GetCookie('count');
if (count == null) {
count=1;
SetCookie('count', count, exp);

window.open(page, "", windowprops);

}
else {
count++;
SetCookie('count', count, exp);
   }
}
//  End -->
</script>
```

But doesn't work because the browser blocks the popup.

Some sites like powvideo or animeflv had a script when the user click anywhere automatically open a new tab like data:text/html;base64,XXXXX

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried my answer below.  can't get much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a flag that can be checked to see if it is still ok to open the popup.

```js
var openPage = true;
function popup() {
  if(openPage){
   window.open ("http://example.com","Window","status=1,toolbar=1,width=500,height=300,resizable=yes");
   openPage = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<body onclick="popup()">
    <h1>Click anywhere!</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: this will fail to work when the user reloads the page, of course dependent on how you want to define `once`

Comment: I would think that a reload would not be considered the same page.

Comment: Just saying, I assumed he don't want this to show up because he tried to do something with cookies

Answer (score 0):

```
<body class="index">

  <h1>Click anywhere!</h1>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var homepage = document.querySelector('body.index');

    var popUp = function(e) {
      window.open ("http://example.com", "Window","status=1,toolbar=1,width=500,height=300,resizable=yes");
      homepage.removeEventListener('click', popUp, false);
    }

    homepage.addEventListener('click', popUp, false);

  </script>


</body>
```

Comment: works on the main page, but when i click in some article and then click anywhere appears again the same popup.

In the site animeflv just open in the first click then i navigate and doesn't appear anymore until i refresh the page.

Comment: I've updated to my answer. If you give the body tag on the homepage a class of 'homepage', it'll work just for that page.

Comment: let me explain better, i want the popup appear just one time, after this don't appear again until the user refresh the website, if he enter in some articles don't appear again. If he enter direct from facebook to article the popup appear then not appear until he refresh the site. The idea is use intrusive ads like ads campaign but only appear one time until he refresh the site or open new tab.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site in question or can you provide an example of what the `<body>` tag looks like in the home page and an article page?

Comment: The site is www.monobyte.ga

Comment: Okay it seems that on the homepage your `body` tag has a class of `index`. We can use that to uniquely identify it, and bind the event only to that. I've updated the snippet. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work, http://powvideo.net/hmrbasn4hr0o this page has a example what i want, when you access and click anywhere open a tab then let you to watch the video, the new tab doesn't appear until you refresh the web or open a new window.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var clickCounter = 0;

function clickMagnet(e){
  if( clickCounter == 0 ) {
    // open window code here
  }
  clickCounter++;
}
</script>
<body onclick="clickMagnet">
```

You need a variable that keeps track of clicks. If it is greater than 0 do nothing.  In my example I bound a function to the body which is triggered by click event.  The clickCounter variable keeps track of clicks. Put your code to open the window inside the if condition where conditionCheck == 0 and you should be good.